# capture clicked link url in google analytics event label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Does anybody know why the value for event label is not getting passed through? I am trying to capture the click url in the event label.

Here is my code.

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('.s-button').click(function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'myevent', 'PDF', url);
});

});
```

Comment: Where are you placing this code? Shouldn't ````var url = $(this).attr('href');```` be inside the ````.click()```` handler or what is ````$(this)```` in the above context?

Comment: @kb, yes i tried that but not able to get the click URL.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this :

```
$('.s-button').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    ga('send', 'event', 'myevent', 'PDF', url);
});
```

The way you do it, the `$(this)` is not referring to the button, but to something bigger, with no href attributes.

Comment: not working. I am actually trying to get the clicked URL

Comment: The element with the class `s.button` is your link ?

Comment: Check at this pen, does you code look like this ? : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyarRp?editors=1010 can you try to log something in your click handler, because I can't see the problem here.